# Trying to update Knockout Js Viewmodel multiple times

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am a newbie in the realm of Knockout JS. I am trying to update my view model after binding with a new JSON object. However, my attempts have been futile. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? (below is my sample fiddle).

JS

```
var strRawJSON = "{\"CPTResults\":[{\"CPT\":{\"RecordKey\":\"b8a335ab-0dda-448d-bb64-943a3cb1b586\",\"Code\":\"82947\",\"Description\":\"Glucose quantitative blood (except reagent strip)\"},\"ErrorA\":\"\",\"ErrorB\":\"\",\"ErrorC\":\"\",\"ErrorD\":\"\",\"ErrorE\":\"\",\"ErrorF\":\"\",\"MedPolicyDesc\":\"Blood Glucose Testing\",\"MedPolicyRef\":\"190.20\",\"MedPolicyWebLink\":\"http:\/\/www.cms.gov\/medicare-coverage-database\/details\/ncd-details.aspx?NCDId=98&ncdver=2&bc=AAAAgAAAAAAA&\",\"Questions\":[{\"Question\":\"If Pre-Diabetic, does the test frequency exceed one screening per 6 months?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"For Individuals diagnosed with Pre-Diabetes, only 2 screening test smay be performed per year, at six-month intervals. Providers should note that these testsd with a pre-diabeted diagnosis must be billed with a V77.1 diagnosis code, and a \\\"TS\\\" modifier to reflect follow up service.\\n\\nPre-Diabetes: abnormal glocose metabolism daignosed froma previous fasting glucose level of 100 to 125 mg\/dl, or a 2-hour post-glucose challenge of 140 to 199 mg\/dl. The term \\\"pre-daibetes\\\" \\nincludes impaired fasting glucose and impaired glucose tolerance.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"},\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"},{\"Question\":\"For Routine Diabetic screening, does the test frequency exceed 1 per year?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"Effective for services on or after January 1, 2005, Medicare will pay for diabetic screening tests under the Medicare Clinical Laboratory Fee Schedule.\\n\\nTo indicate that the purpose of the test(s) is for diabetic screening, a screening diagnosis code (V77.1) is required in the diagnosis section of the claim.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"},\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"}]}]}";
var strRawJSON2 = "{\"CPTResults\":[{\"CPT\":{\"RecordKey\":\"b8a335ab-0dda-448d-bb64-943a3cb1b586\",\"Code\":\"82947\",\"Description\":\"Test quantitative blood (except reagent strip)\"},\"ErrorA\":\"\",\"ErrorB\":\"\",\"ErrorC\":\"\",\"ErrorD\":\"\",\"ErrorE\":\"\",\"ErrorF\":\"\",\"MedPolicyDesc\":\"Blood Glucose Testing\",\"MedPolicyRef\":\"190.20\",\"MedPolicyWebLink\":\"http:\/\/www.cms.gov\/medicare-coverage-database\/details\/ncd-details.aspx?NCDId=98&ncdver=2&bc=AAAAgAAAAAAA&\",\"Questions\":[{\"Question\":\"If Pre-Diabetic, does the test frequency exceed one screening per 6 months?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"For Individuals diagnosed with Pre-Diabetes, only 2 screening test smay be performed per year, at six-month intervals. Providers should note that these testsd with a pre-diabeted diagnosis must be billed with a V77.1 diagnosis code, and a \\\"TS\\\" modifier to reflect follow up service.\\n\\nPre-Diabetes: abnormal glocose metabolism daignosed froma previous fasting glucose level of 100 to 125 mg\/dl, or a 2-hour post-glucose challenge of 140 to 199 mg\/dl. The term \\\"pre-daibetes\\\" \\nincludes impaired fasting glucose and impaired glucose tolerance.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"},\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"},{\"Question\":\"For Routine Diabetic screening, does the test frequency exceed 1 per year?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"Effective for services on or after January 1, 2005, Medicare will pay for diabetic screening tests under the Medicare Clinical Laboratory Fee Schedule.\\n\\nTo indicate that the purpose of the test(s) is for diabetic screening, a screening diagnosis code (V77.1) is required in the diagnosis section of the claim.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"},\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"}]}]}";
var strModifiedJSON = "{\"CPTResults\":[{\"CPT\":{\"RecordKey\":\"b8a335ab-0dda-448d-bb64-943a3cb1b586\",\"Code\":\"82947\",\"Description\":\"Glucose quantitative blood (except reagent strip)\"},\"ErrorA\":\"\",\"ErrorB\":\"\",\"ErrorC\":\"\",\"ErrorD\":\"\",\"ErrorE\":\"Medicare may not pay for this test based on frequency limitations.\",\"ErrorF\":\"\",\"MedPolicyDesc\":\"Blood Glucose Testing\",\"MedPolicyRef\":\"190.20\",\"MedPolicyWebLink\":\"http:\/\/www.cms.gov\/medicare-coverage-database\/details\/ncd-details.aspx?NCDId=98&ncdver=2&bc=AAAAgAAAAAAA&\",\"Questions\":[{\"Question\":\"If Pre-Diabetic, does the test frequency exceed one screening per 6 months?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"For Individuals diagnosed with Pre-Diabetes, only 2 screening test smay be performed per year, at six-month intervals. Providers should note that these testsd with a pre-diabeted diagnosis must be billed with a V77.1 diagnosis code, and a \\\"TS\\\" modifier to reflect follow up service.\\n\\nPre-Diabetes: abnormal glocose metabolism daignosed froma previous fasting glucose level of 100 to 125 mg\/dl, or a 2-hour post-glucose challenge of 140 to 199 mg\/dl. The term \\\"pre-daibetes\\\" \\nincludes impaired fasting glucose and impaired glucose tolerance.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"},{\"Question\":\"For Routine Diabetic screening, does the test frequency exceed 1 per year?\",\"QuestionExplanation\":\"Effective for services on or after January 1, 2005, Medicare will pay for diabetic screening tests under the Medicare Clinical Laboratory Fee Schedule.\\n\\nTo indicate that the purpose of the test(s) is for diabetic screening, a screening diagnosis code (V77.1) is required in the diagnosis section of the claim.\",\"QuestionPossibleAnswers\":[{\"OptionText\":\"Yes\",\"OptionValue\":\"fail\"},{\"OptionText\":\"No\",\"OptionValue\":\"pass\"}],\"QuestionUserAnswer\":null,\"isFrequency\":true,\"ABNStatement\":\"\"}]}]}";
var viewModel;

$('#MedNecContainer').removeClass('hide');
var objViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(strRawJSON, CPTResultsMappingOptionsFunctions);

viewModel = { 
    list: objViewModel
};

console.log('objViewModel.CPTResults.length:' + objViewModel.CPTResults().length);
console.log('viewModel.list.length:' + viewModel.list.length);
console.log('viewModel.list.CPTResults.length:' + viewModel.list.CPTResults().length);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("MedNecContainer"));


setInterval(function() {
    var newList = ko.mapping.fromJS(strModifiedJSON);        
    viewModel.list = newList;
    console.log('reload');
},1000);


function CPTResultsMappingOptionsFunctions() {
    var self = this;
    var i = 0;
    self.setDropdownOnChange = function (elements, data) {
        $(".cpt-question").bind("change", function (event) {
        });

    }
}
```

Html/Templates:

```
<div class="widget hide" id="MedNecContainer">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <h3>Med Nec Results</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>CPT© Code</th>
                        <th>Error E</th>
                        <!--th>Description</th-->
                        <th>Question(s)</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbCPTResults" data-bind="template: { name: 'med-nec-results-row', foreach:list.CPTResults(), 'if': list.CPTResults() && list.CPTResults().length > 0}">  

                </tbody>
            </table>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="tweetsTemplate">
 </script>         


<script type="text/html" id="med-nec-results-row">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
        <!--td data-bind="text: cptAndDescription"></td-->
        <td data-bind="text: CPT.Description"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ErrorE"></td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody data-bind="template: {   name: 'med-nec-results-question-row', 
                                                foreach: Questions(), 
                                                'if': Questions() && Questions().length > 0
                                             }">    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="med-nec-results-question-row">
    <tr class="med-nec-questions">
        <td data-bind="text:Question"></td>
        <!--td data-bind="text:QuestionExplanation"></td-->
        <td>
            <select class="cpt-question" data-bind="options: QuestionPossibleAnswers,  
                                                    optionsText: 'OptionText', 
                                                    value: QuestionUserAnswer, 
                                                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dagr8anil/JBby7/89/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to make `viewModel.list` observable so that your views can react to `list` being assigned to a new value:

   ```
   viewModel = { 
       list: ko.observable(objViewModel)
   };
   ```
2. You also need to call the mapping function the same way you're calling it with the initial data. Also make sure to update the observable by passing it `newList`:

   ```
   var newList = ko.mapping.fromJSON(strModifiedJSON, CPTResultsMappingOptionsFunctions);     
   viewModel.list(newList);
   ```
3. Finally, you'll need to update your `template` binding on the `tbody`:

   ```
   <tbody id="tbCPTResults" data-bind="template: { name: 'med-nec-results-row', foreach:list().CPTResults(), 'if': list().CPTResults() && list().CPTResults().length > 0 }">
   ```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JBby7/91/

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I was also wondering what if i moved this code 

var newList = ko.mapping.fromJSON(strModifiedJSON, CPTResultsMappingOptionsFunctions);     
viewModel.list(newList);

to the self.setDropdownOnChange function, it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @user2014809: If I put a logging statement inside of the function assigning the event handler, it looks like it's never being called.

Comment: ahh i had to create a custom binding for the select onchange to get it to work. Thank you so much for helping me!